# Proving that $\mathbb{F}_p[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1^p,\dots,x_n^p)$ is a complete intersection ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, group-rings, local-rings, artinian

I have found in some sources that the ring  $R=\mathbb{F}_p[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1^p,\dots,x_n^p)$ is a local complete intersection ring.

I need this result in order to apply a related theorem and I would like to understand why this is true. I see why $R$ is local, artinian and injectif. However, for the complete intersection propriety, I don't really understand neither what does it mean.

Clearly we have:

$$\frac{\mathbb{F}_p[x_1,\dots,x_n]}{(x_1^p,\dots,x_n^p)}\simeq \frac{\mathbb{F}_p[x_1]}{(x_1^p)}\otimes\dots\otimes\frac{\mathbb{F}_p[x_n]}{(x_n^p)} $$
so I suppose that proving just $\mathbb{F}_p[x_1]/(x_1^p)$   is a complete intersection ring it is enough and an easier task, but I don't know how to procede anymore.

Comment: What is your definition of complete intersection?

Comment: R is called a complete intersection if for some (hence for any) Cohen presentation of $\hat{R}$ as a homomorphic image of a complete regular local ring $Q$, $\ker(Q\rightarrow\hat{R})$ is generated by a $Q$-regular sequence.

Comment: $k[x]/(x^p)$ is already complete and it is isomorphic to $k[[x]]/(x^p)$, which is as you call it a Cohen presentation. Since $x^p\neq 0$ in $k[[x]]$, which is a domain, it is regular sequence.